# How to translate this IHttpActionResult to ASP.NET Core IActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've got an `IHttpActionResult` in "old" ASP.NET, which has the following code for `ExecuteAsync`:

```
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = _value == null ?
            _request.CreateResponse(StatusCode) :
            _request.CreateResponse(StatusCode, _value);

        if (_uri != null)
        {
            var relativeUri = new Uri(_uri.PathAndQuery, UriKind.Relative);
            response.Headers.Location = relativeUri;
        }
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
```

Now, to translate this to the ASP.NET Core `IActionResult`, I realize that I need to change the signature to

```
    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
```

I have two specific needs:

1. If `_value` is not null, send it back as the body of the response; and
2. If `_uri` is not null, send it back in the `Location` header of the response.

I've found lots of similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36199940/7850), which suggests manipulating the `context`'s `Response` property - but this doesn't answer how to set the body for an `object` (rather than a string), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42594823/7850), which suggests using an `ObjectResponse`, but it isn't clear to me how I would add the required header.

How do you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you definitely could use `ObjectResponse` for this case.

Regarding headers: in `ExecuteResultAsync` method you can directly modify the Response via `context.HttpContext.Response` property, so do something like this:

```
public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
{
    // note: ObjectResult allows to pass null in ctor
    var objectResult = new ObjectResult(_value)
    {
        StatusCode = <needed status_code>
    };

    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers["Location"] = "<your relativeUri>";

    await objectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
}
```